# How to properly use cyclic behaviour of CyclicBarrier for two different set of tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

CyclicBarrier executes the barrier action when the last thread enters the barrier.

If there are 5 parties(threads) defined in CyclicBarrier, then when 5th thread(task) will enter the barrier, the barrier will trip (i.e. will reset) and barrier action will get executed.

Here, it does not matter 5th thread is of what type. It could be any task.

So, my questions are:

1. If there are two set of tasks (each of 5 thread), then how to make sure a particular set of tasks gets executed first and then barrier action command gets executed. 
   And the remaining set of tasks gets executed after that and then again barrier action command gets executed.
2. Whether CyclicBarrier is suitable for these kinds of scenarios or not. 
   If not then how its cyclic behavior can be used properly in real-world scenarios.

Following is the CyclicBarrier code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;


public class CyclicBarrierSimpleExample {
    static int barrierActionThreadCount;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // 5 is the number of parties. So, when the 5th thread will enter the barrier, barrier gets tripped or reset and BarrierAction will be called. 
        final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(5, new BarrierAction(barrierActionThreadCount));

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Thread validationTask = new Thread(new ValidationTask(i, cyclicBarrier));
            validationTask.start();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Thread serviceTask = new Thread(new ServiceTask(i, cyclicBarrier));
            serviceTask.start();
        }
    }
}

class BarrierAction implements Runnable{
    private int barrierActionThreadCount;
    public BarrierAction(int barrierActionThreadCount) {
        this.barrierActionThreadCount=barrierActionThreadCount;
    }
    // Barrier action will execute when barrier is reached i.e. number of parties waiting got executed
    // In this case, it will trip when 5 different threaValidationTaskds are called and then again its number of parties will reset to 5
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.barrierActionThreadCount++;
        System.out.println("Barrier action thread got executed "+barrierActionThreadCount+" times");
    }

}


class ValidationTask implements Runnable{
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier; 
    int threadNum;
    public ValidationTask(int threadNum, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.threadNum = threadNum;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(threadNum*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Validation Task: Thread-"+threadNum+" got executed");
        try {

            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

class ServiceTask implements Runnable{
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier; 
    int threadNum;
    public ServiceTask(int threadNum, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.threadNum = threadNum;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Service Task: Thread-"+threadNum+" got executed");
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output of above task:

```
Validation Task: Thread-0 got executed
Service Task: Thread-1 got executed
Service Task: Thread-0 got executed
Service Task: Thread-4 got executed
Service Task: Thread-2 got executed
Service Task: Thread-3 got executed
Barrier action thread got executed 1 times
Validation Task: Thread-1 got executed
Validation Task: Thread-2 got executed
Validation Task: Thread-3 got executed
Validation Task: Thread-4 got executed
Barrier action thread got executed 2 times
```

Behaviour I am expecting is that all validation tasks should be executed first, and thereafter service task should be executed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While surfing about Semaphore, just came around with an interesting article about the difference between CountDownLatch, CyclicBarrier, and Semaphore. Wanted to share it with you all: 
http://shazsterblog.blogspot.in/2011/12/comparison-of-countdownlatch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for 1st Question:
As mentioned by Andreas CountDownlatch can be used in the scenario you mentioned.

Answer for 2nd Question:
Below is the code to use the cyclic behavior of CyclicBarrier.

Here in this example 5 threads are using CyclicBarrier and calling await() method multiple time to arrive and wait simultaneously at multiple checkpoint.

```
 package dev.cyclicbarrier;

import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class CyclicBehaviorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(5, new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("All threads Arrived at barrier Checkpoint");
            }

        });

        Thread t1= new Thread(new Task(barrier),"thread-1");
        Thread t2= new Thread(new Task(barrier),"thread-2");
        Thread t3= new Thread(new Task(barrier),"thread-3");
        Thread t4= new Thread(new Task(barrier),"thread-4");
        Thread t5= new Thread(new Task(barrier),"thread-5");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }

}

class Task implements Runnable {
    CyclicBarrier barrier;

    Task(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has started for checkpoint 1");
            barrier.await();

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has started for checkpoint 2");
            barrier.await();

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has started for checkpoint 3");
            barrier.await();

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "has finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output for the above program is

```
    thread-2 has started for checkpoint 1
    thread-4 has started for checkpoint 1
    thread-1 has started for checkpoint 1
    thread-3 has started for checkpoint 1
    thread-5 has started for checkpoint 1
    All threads Arrived at barrier Checkpoint
    thread-2 has started for checkpoint 2
    thread-4 has started for checkpoint 2
    thread-5 has started for checkpoint 2
    thread-1 has started for checkpoint 2
    thread-3 has started for checkpoint 2
    All threads Arrived at barrier Checkpoint
    thread-3 has started for checkpoint 3
    thread-2 has started for checkpoint 3
    thread-4 has started for checkpoint 3
    thread-5 has started for checkpoint 3
    thread-1 has started for checkpoint 3
    All threads Arrived at barrier Checkpoint
    thread-1has finished
    thread-3has finished
    thread-2has finished
    thread-4has finished
    thread-5has finished
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't use a barrier of size 5 to control 10 threads.

You use a barrier of size 5 to control 5 threads, where each thread executes a series of operations, waiting for all threads to complete a step, before continuing with the next step.

If you want to start 10 threads, and have the 5 `ServiceTask` threads wait for the 5 `ValidationTask` threads to complete, then use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), give it to both `ValidationTask` and `ServiceTask`.

The `ServiceTask` should then call `await​()` at beginning, and the `ValidationTask` should call `countDown​()` at the end.

That way no `ServiceTask` run before all `ValidationTask` completes, and the `ValidationTask` can stop individually as soon as they are done, and don't all have to wait on each other before stopping.

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas- That is perfectly fine using the CountDownLatch but actually I am trying to simulate the cyclic behavior of CyclicBarrier.  Suppose, in real-world example if there are multiple sets of tasks rather than 2 provided in the current scenario then every time I need to create a latch with 5 counts and call the await() function as you mentioned. But, then how the barrier of CyclicBarrier can be re-used in real scenarios. What is the significance of CyclicBarrier over CountDownLatch.

Comment: @SKumar You were creating a new thread for each "task". What you really needed was just 5 threads, that each go through a sequence of tasks in order. So your thread code would be something like `runTask1(); barrier.await(); runTask2(); barrier.await(); runTask3(); barrier.await(); ...`. That way all 5 threads would complete task 1 before any of them start task 2, and all would complete task 2 before any of them start task 3. That only uses 5 threads and 1 barrier, not the 15 threads your attempt would require, where 10 of the threads were always asleep anyway.

Comment: @Andreas- Agreed but in CyclicBarrier, barrier.await() are called in the parties(threads) started from the main thread rather than in the main thread as in CountDownLatch. Here, trigger point is tripping and action performed is the ActionBarrier once tripping is done. The way which I could think of to achieve this is: we need to define runTask2() in BarrierAction. But to make sure runTask3() gets executed after runTask1() and runTask2(), we need to create another CyclicBarrier object in BarrierAction and define runTask3() in another BarrierAction.

Comment: @SKumar Sorry, didn't follow that at all. Neither CyclicBarrier nor CountDownLatch is used by the main thread. Only the worker threads use them. --- If task 3 cannot run until task 2 is done, and task 2 cannot run until task 1 is done, it's implicit that task 3 cannot run until task 1 is done. There is no need for explicit rule between task 1 and task 3.

Comment: @Andreas- Sorry for the late reply. Just hung up with other works and also needed time to explore more about it. I just wanted to state here that if CyclicBarrier object is created in the main thread then in the worker thread barrier.await() is called, contrary to CountDownLatch, where latch.await() function is called in the main thread after all threads execution started.

Comment: @Andreas- Now coming to my question it's implicit that task 3 cannot run until task 1 is done. I just wanted to know, how it can be achieved. And, I just realized that sequential execution of the different set of tasks is the best way to achieve it (mentioned in your earlier comment). Thanks for your reply and the explanation you provided. Created a fiddle for it: https://ideone.com/K7lvfK